# Spring DeferredResult progress bar

Tags: java, jquery, spring

I´m using a Spring deferredResult to make a async request between client-server. I know that the reason to use this technique is precisely to keep the request between client-server as idle, until the server finish the job.

But I was wondering if it would be possible some how that the server will let know the client how much time keep the job to be finish. 
I want that information to provide a progress bar on the client side.

Any suggestion?.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe so, as the server's first response will be the data requested by the async call.  It would take a second async call to return some data such as the average response time by the server, but even then, the server would not be able to determine the lag time between the server and the client, the server would only be able to determine how long it took to run the process called by the async request.  You could set a timeout that would cancel the request (or at least ignore the response), but that would be on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

I used the **deferredResult** for similar functionality. On the client side write a javascript method which will call itself once over. e.g.

```
function updateDisplay(finished){
    if(!finished){
        $.ajax({
           url:"url to the function",
           success:function(){
              updateDisplay
              this.data: //status
           },
           complete:funtion (){
               updateDisplay(this.data);
           }
        }
    }
 }
```

in this way you can send periodic information from the server to client and update the status.

Comment: The job that the deferredResult is checking to be finish is done by multiple async request, so I dont think it will be easy to determine the progress. And I think is a little bit overkill about what I want to achieve, but thanks!.